# Lead sharing criteria Rule doesnt work

Tags: sharing, leads

I'm facing some issues regarding the visibity of Leads using Sharing criteria Rule I'll explaing myself:

1. I maked the Lead object to private.
2. Make a sharing cirteria Rule using a picklist field value to match the criteria
3. Share all record with the values with a Role and subordinates

Then i tried  with a User in arole below the Role that i set up and teh user hasnt got the edit access, but it gained the permission to view.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your Sharing Rule granted the user **Read** access, but not **Read/Write** Access.

This should be configurable in the Sharing Rule definition. Please ensure that the Sharing rule is granting Read/Write access and not just Read Access. That should resolve it.

[image: Grant Lead Access on Sharing Rule: Read/Write]

A useful way to diagnose record access is by opening the record of interest and clicking on the ['Sharing' button](https://theeverydayadmin.com/2018/12/11/time-saving-tips-back-to-the-future-wait-i-mean-classic-to-discover-the-power-of-the-sharing-button/).

Clicking this button will show you everyone who has access to the record and how they have this access. (i.e, from Sharing Rule, Account Team, etc..)

I believe this button is only available in Salesforce Classic at the moment, so you may need to switch, but I believe they are [finally] implementing this in lightning coming soon (a.k.a Spring '21 Release)